# How to update field based on original value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents with format like the following:

```
{
  "user-agent": "\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko\"",
  "log_version": "LOG_ACCESS_150001"
}
```

For field `user-agent`, some documents's values are wrapped by quote `"`, as above, while others are not. Is there a way to trim the double quote if existed?

I've tried to use script to do the work, but didn't find documents about updating field based on original value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this, unfortunately. You'll have to write a tiny application, which would:

1. Retrieve these documents
2. Store your documents somewhere temporarily
3. Replace quotes in your `user-agent` field
4. Re-index them with same `_id` in order to update(replace) them.